# Magento 2: Override Price-options.js

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I've overridden `price-options.js`'s function `_onOptionChanged()`, but I got the error on changes variable to get `defaultGetOptionValue()` function.

**requirejs-config**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-options': {
                 'VENDOR_MODULE/js/price-options': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**price-options.js**

```
define([
     'jquery',
     'underscore',
     'mage/template',
     'priceUtils',
     'priceBox',
     'jquery/ui'
 ], function ($, _, mageTemplate, utils) {
     'use strict';
     return function (priceOptions) {
         return $.widget('mage.priceOptions', priceOptions, {

             _onOptionChanged: function onOptionChanged(event) {
             ...
             else{
                    changes = defaultGetOptionValue(option, this.options.optionConfig);
                 } 
             ...
```

**Error from console**

```
ReferenceError: defaultGetOptionValue is not defined
```

Comment: Did you override the whole file? Sounds like you didn't copy the rest of the file including the function definition for `defaultGetOptionValue`

Comment: I'm using mixin to override the price-options.js, I try to copy the default GetOptionValue functions, no error appears. But the code is not working.

Comment: Thanks @ManashviBirla, I'm learn to mixin js from that link. I can override price-options.js but some functions outside the $.widget is not defined.